# Hebrew table of contents number format

Tags: table-of-contents, hebrew

I am writing a mathematical document in Hebrew and I "forced" the page numbers to be the English font (using \selectlanguage) so they will be *consistent* with the font used in the formulas. However, my table of contents uses the different (smaller, to me stranger) font used in Hebrew for section and page numbers. Is there anyway to change that, perhaps by redefining a command?[image: snippet from Hebrew ToC]

Thanks for the answers. John's "\def" worked and I added similar definitions for chapter and sections. I hope I did it correctly.

The only problem is that I get "Please insert into preamble" at the start of the toc, but it is not really a problem because it goes away upon a third run of pdflatex.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

\def\thepage{\bgroup\selectlanguage{english}\arabic{page}\egroup}
\def\thesection{\bgroup\selectlanguage{english}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}\egroup}
\def\thechapter{\bgroup\selectlanguage{english}\arabic{chapter}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\tableofcontents

\selectlanguage{english}
\newpage
\selectlanguage{hebrew}

\chapter{פרק ראשון}
\section{סעיף ראשון בפרק ראשון}
\section{סעיף שני בפרק ראשון}

\selectlanguage{english}
\newpage
\selectlanguage{hebrew}

\chapter{פרק שני}
\section{סעיף ראשון בפרק שני}
\section{סעיף שני בפרק שני}

\selectlanguage{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you add a mwe? and welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just guessing, but try `\def\thepage{\bgroup\selectlanguage{english}\arabic{page}\egroup}` in the preamble (after babel, natch).

Comment: This will depend, among other things, on your document class. A MCVE is important here.

Comment: The Koma classes, for example, define the font styles `partentrypagenumber`, `chapterentrypagenumber` and `sectionentrypagenumber`, so switching to `\documentclass{scrartcl}`, `scrreprt` or `scrbook` might work for you.